# Is it possible for a worker to stop it's own thread with signal/slot connection in Qt?

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, worker, worker-thread

I'm trying to implement threaded worker for parallel computation. The problem I encountered is that the `quit()` slot of `thread` is not triggered, therefore applications waits at `while(thread->isRunning())`. Is it possible to stop `thread` from `worker` using signal-slot connection between them?
Here is my code:

> main.cpp:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include "workermanager.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    WorkerManager workerManager;
    workerManager.process();
    return a.exec();
}
```

> worker.h:

```
#include <QObject>
#include <QDebug>

class Worker : public QObject
{
   Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Worker(QObject *parent = 0) :
        QObject(parent){}

signals:
    void processingFinished();

public slots:
    void process()
    {
        qDebug() << "processing";
        emit this->processingFinished();
    }
};
```

> workermanager.h:

```
#include "worker.h"
#include <QThread>

class WorkerManager : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit WorkerManager(QObject *parent = 0) :
        QObject(parent){}

    void process()
    {
        QThread* thread = new QThread;
        Worker* worker = new Worker;

        connect(thread,SIGNAL(started()),worker,SLOT(process()));
        connect(worker,SIGNAL(processingFinished()),thread,SLOT(quit()));

        worker->moveToThread(thread);
        thread->start();
        qDebug() << "thread started";
        while(thread->isRunning())
        {
        }
        qDebug() << "thread finished";

       //further operations - e.g. data collection from workers etc.

    }
};
```

Comment: It's not clear how you expect this to work given that your current implementation is synchronous. Do you intend for `WorkerManager` to live on its own thread? If so then it can just run the event loop for that thread.

Comment: `worker` lives in the worker thread, and `thread` lives in the main thread, so the `processingFinished` signal will be sent via a queued connection. The `quit` slot will therefore be called by the main thread's event loop, but the event loop is not being processed in your `while` loop.

Answer (score 0):

That while loop blocks your thread and prevents it from processing any signals, if you really want to wait for the thread to finish, you need to start an event loop.

Try this instead:

```
void process()
{
    QThread* thread = new QThread;
    Worker* worker = new Worker;

    connect(thread,SIGNAL(started()),worker,SLOT(process()));
    connect(worker,SIGNAL(processingFinished()),thread,SLOT(quit()));

    worker->moveToThread(thread);

    QEventLoop loop;
    connect(thread, &QThread::finished, &loop, &QEventLoop::quit);
    qDebug() << "thread started";
    thread->start();
    loop.exec();
    qDebug() << "thread finished";

   //further operations - e.g. data collection from workers etc.

}
```

But I have to admit I don't really see the point of this code. If you need to wait for the task to finish to keep doing stuff, you might as well run it directly.
There at least your program will be able to process other things (if there are some) in the mean time.